# public website with sapui5 and without credentials

Tags: sapui5

I want to create public website(actually web page), with some inputs and send the data back to sap. My problem is that the website should be open for everyone and still be connected to sap(which requires username and password).
Is there a way to create sapui5 website without the need to give credentials(and still keep the sap system safe)?

Comment: You can add a technical user to the SICF node of the app and the OData service, then there is no need for a visitor of your site to log in.

Comment: Be very careful with this - if your application will create data in your SAP system and your company is still on per user pricing (rather than per document) this could run you afoul of indirect licensing rules and get you in some hot water come audit time.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mean to work with the user information/authentication which I assume is true because you do not want the user to log in, in that case, you can

1. Create a destination in SCP with basic authentication and store the username and password of the backend system you wish to communicate. [An example to refer destination creation in SCP](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hcp-create-destination.html)
2. Deploy the app in the SAP Cloud platform using the destination in your app to post the data.

Hope this should solve your problem.

Some more references:

- [how to set the authentication method to none in UI5 app in SAP Cloud Platform](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/aed1ffa3f3e741b3a4573c9e475aa2a4.html)
- [How to deploy a simple UI5 app to SCP](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/02/14/steps-to-deploy-a-simple-sapui5-application-in-cloud-platform-using-sap-web-ide/)
- [Get a free trial account of SAP Cloud Platform](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/hcp-create-trial-account.html)